# Data loss warning rebuilding RAID1 logical drive

Tags: windows, raid-1

I have a Windows 7 Pro server running RAID1 and from the log, it appears that it 'lost' a drive for a few seconds and now thinks that the RAID1 has failed.

I assume it needs rebuilding, which I understand, but it gives a data loss warning when I press 'rebuild' which is making me hesitate...

There should be no data loss, is this correct?

Just tried to post images, but I can't!

Comment: "Windows 7 Pro" I get, "Server" I get, but if you think there is such a thing as a "Windows 7 Pro server" then you're very much in the wrong place sorry. This site if for professional sysadmins, who inherently use server operating system on their servers. I've voted to move this to SuperUser.com, if enough users agree it'll just automatically move ok.

Comment: Man these places can be harsh sometimes! I didn't mean it was a professional server, I meant it was running Windows 7 Professional... Thanks for moving the post.

Comment: You need to read what these sites are about - serverfault.com is ONLY about professional server situations.

Comment: OK, fair point, apologies.